# Database table columns missing in MySqlWorkBench, working with v6.3 so not an upgrade issue

Tags: mysql-workbench

I know that another question of same title exists, but I am new and unable to leave a comment there.

After 6 months of using MySQLWorkBench v6.3, all of a sudden I can no longer edit my table columns.

When I click on the tool icon next to the table name in the scheme, all of the fields I would need to edit for columns are disabled and empty.

I can see my indexes.
I can see my foreign keys.
I can see all the columns listed in the tree under the schema.
But I can't see any columns in the Columns tab for that table.

This just started happening this week.  I've tried rebooting, refreshing, and giving my PC some rest and relaxation.

Any other ideas?

The last thing I did in my database was add a foreign key, which was successful.  After that, starting having column issue.  Not sure if that's a clue or not.

Comment: Is it perhaps this problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79160 ?

Comment: Oh HAPPINESS!  Thank you for directing me there for that work-around!